# Cannot find libGame.so even after running build_native.sh in Cygwin?

Tags: android, cygwin, cocos2d-x

**EDIT THREE:**

Just re-ran build_native.sh (**After EDIT TWO**)

This time it ran smoothly and there were no problems with CCCommon.cpp,I even see that libGame.so is being built finally (Even in android project under libs).

**However I'm still getting the same issue from the Android.mk file in EDIT TWO below (Please view the image).**

*Am I getting closer, missing some step somewhere?*

**EDIT TWO:**

After following Vikas's suggestion and blog and linking folders (Thankyou Vikas!):

I found an error in the Android.mk file of my project.

Here's an image of what it looks like: 
[image]

I have also added what my build_native.sh looks like for reference, in case anything is screwy in there:

**build_native.sh:**

```
# set params
```

NDK_ROOT=/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r9c
COCOS2DX_ROOT=/cygdrive/c/Users/DarkRaveDev/Documents/cocos2d-x-2.0.1
GAME_ROOT=$COCOS2DX_ROOT/CHAARA
GAME_ANDROID_ROOT=$GAME_ROOT/proj.android
RESOURCE_ROOT=$GAME_ROOT/Resources

buildexternalsfromsource=

usage(){
cat << EOF
usage: $0 [options]

Build C/C++ native code using Android NDK

OPTIONS:
   -s   Build externals from source
   -h   this help
EOF
}

while getopts "s" OPTION; do
    case "$OPTION" in
        s)
            buildexternalsfromsource=1
            ;;
        h)
            usage
            exit 0
            ;;
    esac
done

```
# make sure assets is exist
```

if [ -d $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/assets ]; then
    rm -rf $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/assets
fi

mkdir $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/assets

```
# copy resources
```

for file in $RESOURCE_ROOT/*
do
    if [ -d "$file" ]; then
        cp -rf "$file" $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/assets
    fi

```
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    cp "$file" $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/assets
fi
```

done

```
# copy icons (if they exist)
```

file=$GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/assets/Icon-72.png
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    cp $file $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png
fi
file=$GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/assets/Icon-48.png
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    cp $file $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png
fi
file=$GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/assets/Icon-32.png
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    cp $file $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png
fi

if [[ $buildexternalsfromsource ]]; then
    echo "Building external dependencies from source"
    $NDK_ROOT/ndk-build -C $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT \
        NDK_MODULE_PATH=${COCOS2DX_ROOT}:${COCOS2DX_ROOT}/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/source
else
    echo "Using prebuilt externals"
    $NDK_ROOT/ndk-build -C $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT \
        NDK_MODULE_PATH=${COCOS2DX_ROOT}:${COCOS2DX_ROOT}/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt
fi

**END-OF-build_native.sh ----------------------**

What step could I be missing?

**EDIT ONE:**

After following Vikas's suggestion from the comments I came up with the following results:

1. I deleted the obj folder in my android project.
2. Re-ran build_native.sh
3. Noticed CCCommon.cpp is not compiling as expected.

Log showing CCCommon.cpp compile problems (Doesn't show creation of libGame.so):

[image]

Log from Logcat(Android) showing cannot find library error(libs folder missing .so file):

[image]

**BACKGROUND:**

I am running this on my device - Samsung s3 4.3

I am using this tutorial : [Building Monetizing Game Apps on Android by Todd Perkins](http://www.lynda.com/Android-tutorials/Building-Monetizing-Game-Apps-Android/107169-2.html)

**I've gotten as far as:**

1. Installing Cygwin
2. Running create-android-project.bat and having it make my android project
3. Running build_native.sh in Cygwin and getting it to make all the .cpp files required.
4. **Getting the android project imported without errors** YAY!

**PROBLEM:**

```
01-08 14:48:44.644: E/AndroidRuntime(25750): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load game from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.chaara.darkravedev-2.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.chaara.darkravedev-2]: findLibrary returned null
```

**Now I have been on SO for a while and the most common solution is to re-run or make sure you haven't forgotten to run the build_native.sh file.**

The Library it seems to be looking for is libGame.so(According to SO) which should be found in your project/libs/armeabi folder - For me its non existent.

**What I have done so far:**

1. Re-run build_native.sh:

[image: After minSDK mismatch changed minSDK to 9 in AndroidManifest.xml]

When I look back into the libs folder there is only these 2 files:

[image]

**Question:**

Why is my libGame.so file not being built?

**Additional Information:**

Crashes on the line with System.loadLibrary("game");

I'm using ndk r9 while the tutorial is using ndk r8

Comment: Are you trying to run on emulator? Or any device, mention device here? It may be issue of different architecture type.

Comment: I did mention I'm running on my device Samsung s3 4.3 Android. I'm not running on emulator.

Comment: From your cmd log `CCCommon.cpp` file failed to compile. Can you just clean and rebuild whole cocos2dx. it might be issue with residue object files earlier compiled. So just delete `obj` directory and build your project again. This error is preventing to build your `yourgame.so` file and thus forcefully running application on device might throw `UnsatisfiedLinkException`

Comment: I have tried your suggestion Vikas(Thank you!) and updated my question with the result. libGame.so is not being built. Any idea why ccommon.cpp is giving problems? I know from SO that I should be seeing "creating libGame.so" somewhere in the cmd log, but CCCommon.cpp failing isn't allowing that.

Comment: This might be issue with file permissions because when you create project using batch file then internally it calls linux based script using cygwin and some files are being created with higher privilege therefore either you have to set recursive permissions for all your project files and folder for full ownership of current user. I suggest you to use latest cocos2dx version which require less efforts and is more reliable. However you can get rid of this problem. Just look at my blog post here : http://patidarvikas.blogspot.in/2013/09/build-and-run-cocos2dx-android-project.html

Comment: Add this line `APP_CPPFLAGS += -Wno-error=format-security` to your `Application.mk` to let compiler to suppress all those warnings. This might solve your issue. Otherwise you can just try my blog post link and just ignore 3rd and 4th steps and directly link Resources folder as `assets`

Comment: Linking folders to eclipse: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/39723?r=39800#message-39800

Comment: I'll get started on this soon! Thanks vikas! If all goes well, please post all solution/suggestion as an answer. I want to give you the points :)

Comment: Hi Vikas, followed your blog, but now I seem to be having another problem altogether with the Android.mk file - Persistent error - No clue why its happening. Have I missed a step somewhere?

Comment: VIKAS! The sample is running!!!! I got rid of the last Android.mk error by going to Properties>C/C++ Build > Builder Settings Tab > Unchecking default build and entering the following: bash ${workspace_loc:/com.chaara.darkravedev}/build_native.sh NDK-DEBUG=1 V=1} (I got this from the tutorial). You have HELPED immensely, please answer the question, and I will mark it as correct!

Comment: Glad to know it worked. I will not answer it because the question is very specific and cocos2dx project is changing at very fast pace and now they have setup python scripts. These errors are because of different different sdk combinations. Meanwhile you dont need cygwin to build android ndk projects. Just delete the question.